# Redirection on the last Slideshow-Element with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to Jquery and want to realize a manual slideshow with a page-redirect on the last "next"-button.

I detect the last Slide-Element with CSS-Classes and then I want to add a Class to the next button to declare that it is the last next-button of the whole Slideshow.

The half of my Code works :) – If I navigate to the last Slide-Element, Jquery adds the Class "last" to the button and if I click on the button with this Class, I'm redirected to the next page – that's what I want.
But if I navigate to the last Slide-Element, then click a few times the "prev"-button and then again the next button, I'm instantly redirected although the Class "last" was removed.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Here's my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$("#image_nav a:first").attr('id', 'firstSlide');
$("#image_nav a:last").attr('id', 'lastSlide');

$(".dritte_ebene li:first").attr('id', 'firstNavi');
$(".dritte_ebene li:last").attr('id', 'lastNavi');

//Redirect to the next page
$("a").click(function(){                       
if ($("#lastSlide").hasClass("activeSlide")) {
$("#weiter").addClass("last");
$('.slide').cycle('pause');
    $(".last").click(function(){   
    window.location.replace("[+PJN_next+]");    
    }); 
}
});     

//Remove "last" if prev is clicked
$('#zurueck').click(function(){   
$("#weiter").removeClass("last");
}); 


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to unbind the added click function. Thus the next time you click `.last` the redirect is performed. Change your code to this. To allow you to unbind only the redirect function.

```
var lastHandler = function() {
    window.location.replace("[+PJN_next+]");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image_nav a:first").attr('id', 'firstSlide');
    $("#image_nav a:last").attr('id', 'lastSlide');

    $(".dritte_ebene li:first").attr('id', 'firstNavi');
    $(".dritte_ebene li:last").attr('id', 'lastNavi');

    //Redirect to the next page
    $("a").click(function() {
        if ($("#lastSlide").hasClass("activeSlide")) {
            $("#weiter").addClass("last").click(lastHandler);
            $('.slide').cycle('pause');
        }
    });

    //Remove "last" if prev is clicked
    $('#zurueck').click(function() {
        $(".last").removeClass("last").unbind('click', lastHandler);
    });
});
```